# creating an array Javascript breakout game

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

I'm creating a simple breakout clone using HTML5 Canvas and have come across the loadHitGrid() function, but I'm having difficulty understanding what it does.

It looks like its creating arrays within the hitgrid array
and then filling this with 1's

Can someone help or draw this out?

```js
function loadHitGrid() {
  for (var i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    hitGrid[i] = new Array;

    for (var j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
      hitGrid[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }

}


//Can i replace hitGrid with the following?


hitGrid = [
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // is this the same as the above????
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1
]





function drawblocks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) { // loops  trough number of rows
      for (var j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) { // loops thgrough number of cols
        if (hitGrid[i][j] == 1) { // for each row / col check for 1
          ctx.beginPath(); // Satrts a new path used when drawing!
          ctx.fillStyle = colours[i];
          ctx.fillRect(j * (blockW + SPACING) + SPACING, 
                       i * (blockH + SPACING) + SPACING, blockW, blockH);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: you could, if NUM_ROWS and NUM_COLS is always 5. You could also use `new Array(NUM_COLS).fill(1);` for the inner part instead of a loop.

Comment: Just a note: You *could* have answered this question on your own by adding the line `console.log(JSON.stringify(hitGrid, null, 2))` in your code.  The `JSON.stringify` pretty-prints the result for you it is formatted nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This would be :

```
hitGrid = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], // is this the same as the above????
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]];
```

Of course that means that NUM_ROWS, and NUM_COLUMNS is 5 :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my comments on the code below:

```
     function loadHitGrid () {     
          for(var i = 0 ; i < NUM_ROWS ; i ++) {
              hitGrid[i] = new Array; //Creating an empty array NUM_ROWS amount of times

              for(var j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j ++) {
                   hitGrid[i][j] = 1 ; //Populating each newly created empty array with NUM_COLS amount of ones.
              }
          }
      }
```

So in NUM_ROWS and NUM_COLS both equal 5 and assuming hitGrid was an empty array, the output would look more like:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Comment: Thanks all, that now makes sense

Comment: Sure thing! :) Be sure to upvote answers you like or select answers if they solve your problem. The reputations of users on Stack Overflow are important!